# Sitecore 7 Search Index Issue

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore7

I want to restrict the search index in Sitecore 7 to only scan one node of the content tree.

Currently the structure looks like this:

- sitecore

  - content

    - BaseNode
    - $Company Node

The index is indexing both `BaseNode` & `$Company Node`, but I only want it to index `$Company Node`.

I've updated the default `/sitecore/content` path in `Sitecore.ContentSearch.config`, `SitecoreContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config`, `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.Index.Master`, and `Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneIndex.Web.config`.  When I updated the `<root>` element to point to `/sitecore/content/$CompanyNode`, I get the following exception when I try to rebuild the indexes.

Any ideas what I need to do to restrict Lucene to just index some items, and not everything?

```
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException 
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. 
Source: mscorlib 
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature         sig, Boolean constructor) 
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[]     parameters, Object[] arguments) 
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr,     Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) 
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) 
at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(Object obj, Object[] properties) 
at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[]     parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) 
at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters,     Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) 
at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters,     Boolean assert) 
at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) 
at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) 
at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) 
at Sitecore.Search.SearchManager.get_SearchConfiguration() 
at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Search.RebuildSearchIndex.RebuildSearchIndexForm.GetIndexes() 
at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Search.RebuildSearchIndex.RebuildSearchIndexForm.BuildIndexes() 

Nested Exception 

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException 
Message: Root item is not defined 
Source: Sitecore.Kernel 
at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsNotNull(Object value, String message) 
at Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.Initialize(Index index) 
at Sitecore.Search.Index.AddCrawler(ICrawler crawler)
```

Comment: Please mark a correct answer or provide more information. :)

Comment: hi Andrew, I'm working with another resource to gather more info.  I'm think we will implement your solution, but right now this task got stuck on to the 'waiting' task list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are attempting to modify the Master Lucene Index file.  I believe that would break a lot of things in the end and I would recommend that you create a new Lucene Index file.

If you were to create a new Index:  Place this index in your App_Config / Include Folder

Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.Index.Alexander.config

In that config you set the crawler to search for your node.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
     <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
      <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
       <index id="alexander_search_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
        <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
        <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>
        <!-- This initializes index property store. Id has to be set to the index id -->
        <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
        <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
          <!-- NOTE: order of these is controls the execution order -->
          <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync" />
        </strategies>
        <commitPolicy hint="raw:SetCommitPolicy">
          <policy type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.TimeIntervalCommitPolicy, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
        </commitPolicy>
        <commitPolicyExecutor hint="raw:SetCommitPolicyExecutor">
          <policyExecutor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
        </commitPolicyExecutor>
        <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
          <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Crawlers.DefaultCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
            <Database>web</Database>
            <Root>/sitecore/content/$Company Node</Root>
          </crawler>
        </locations>
       </index>
     </indexes>
   </configuration>
  </contentSearch>
 </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

This above index will index everything under that node.
In C# you can easily call this with.

```
ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("alexander_search_index").Rebuild();

using (var searchContext = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("alexander_search_index").CreateSearchContext())
   {
       var result = searchContext.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
           .Where(//Put Query Here);

       //do ForEach if you return multiple and so on.

       if (result != null)
              Context.Item = result.GetItem();
   }
```

You can also Rebuild your indexes and verify that they are working by going into Sitecore -> Control Panel -> Indexing -> Indexing Manager.  After doing that you should see the Index.

Another Edit:
You could also just perform your C# Search underneath that item in the content tree and use only the web database.

```
 Item bucketItem = //Code to get $Company Node as a Sitecore Item
  //Probably Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("Guid for $Company Node")

 using (var searchContext = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(bucketItem as      IIndexable).CreateSearchContext())
  {
     try
     {
          var result = searchContext.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(x => x.Name == itemName).FirstOrDefault();
             if (result != null)
                 Context.Item = result.GetItem();
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         //Do something
     }
  }
```